# Workflow email notification template

Tags: aem

I have created custom workflow  for reviewing the content before publishing if the content is okay admin will approve if it needs any changes admin will reject the content. in both cases workflow send email to the initiator?
by default its taking input template from /etc/workflow/notification/email/default/en.txt

when i made changes to this file its not reflecting in that workflow email notification to the user. I want to customize the template. Is there anyway to overcome this problem?

Comment: That is the correct way to customise. Your workflows are using cached version of the template so try restarting AEM or the email (com.day.cq.mailer.DefaultMailService) service.

Comment: I did but it is not working.

Comment: I tried this on an OOTB 6.2 instance and it works. Have you got any other customisation? What version are you using?

Comment: i am using 6.1 version

Comment: Testing it in 6.1 OOTB and it worked for me. You want to try that?

Answer (score 0):

Restarting com.day.cq.mailer.DefaultMailService on 6.3 solved the same issue for me. Restarting the whole AEM also worked, btw.